# String manipulation on each noteproperty value

Tags: string, powershell, foreach

tried many different methods of trying to get this working.  The is the closest non-working example i can come up with.

I want to get rid of NoteProperty items with a null value, if i also want to get rid of $ and ; characters from any NoteProperty value in an object while leaving the rest of the value behind could someone please advise me what is wrong with the following code example?

```
$JournalObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | ForEach-Object {
    if ($JournalObject.$_.Value -like ';')
    {
    $JournalObject.$_.Value.Replace(';', '')
    }
    if ($JournalObject.$_.Value -like '$')
    {
    $JournalObject.$_.Value.Replace('$', '')
    }
    if ($JournalObject.$_.Value -eq $null)
    {
    $JournalObject.PSObject.Properties.Remove($_)
    }
}
```

Kindest regards !!
hoping for your help :)

Comment: Strings are immutable in .NET, so `String.Replace` does not modify the string. Also `-like ';'` and `-like '$'` will look for exact match.

Comment: Any example of what would work to achieve the same goal please ?

Answer (score 0):

Something to also note; if you are running a replace that's getting it's object from `Get-Member`, you aren't touching the original object to begin with.

You can see this for yourself by running another `Get-Member` where your `ForEach-Object` is to see what's being passed through the pipeline (spoiler, it's `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition`)

You can also see this a little better by running it against a string with 1 `Get-Member` piped then comparing it with a second `Get-Member` piped:

`"asfdasf" | Get-Member` (this will return the expected String type)

VS

`"asfdasf" | Get-Member | Get-Member` (this will comeback as a MemberDefinition object, since you're literally getting the members of the Get-Member result)

Working on a better approach, will update this answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. First you need to prune out the the properties you aren't returning so that you aren't loop in on members that will no longer exist, by finding those members then excluding with `select-object`.

Then you can loop through and fix the values.

```
$members = $JournalObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -expandproperty name
$removelist = $JournalObject | % {
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        if ($_.$member -eq $null) {
            $member
        }
    }
}
$uremovelist = $removelist | select -unique
$prunedJournalObject = $JournalObject | select * -ExcludeProperty $uremovelist
$members = $prunedJournalObject | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -expandproperty
$prunedJournalObject | % {
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        if ($_.$member -match ';') {
            $_.$member = $_.$member.Replace(';', '')
        }
        if ($_.$member -match '$') {
            $_.$member = $_.$member.Replace('$', '')
        }
    }
    $_
}
```